# Ebean ManyToMany: How to optimize the fetching of a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: database, performance, persistence, ebean

I am building a WebApp with PLAY 2.2.1, Ebean and want to optimize the fetching of a list of entities the is associated to another entity through a ManyToMany relationship.

More precisely I am fetching a list of books:

```
@Entity
public class Book extends Model {

    @Id
    @Column(name="book_id")
    public int bookId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="book_author", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName = "book_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName = "author_id")})
    public List<Author> authors;
}
```

...and each book is associated with a list of authors:

```
@Entity
public class Author extends Model {

    @Id
    @Column(name="author_id")
    public int authorId;
}
```

The code to create the query and fetch its results is

```
Query<Book> queryBooks = Ebean.createQuery(Book.class);
queryBooks.where("...");
FutureList<Book> fLBooks = queryBooks.findFutureList();

if (fLBooks.isDone()){
    List<Book> books = fLBooks.get();
}
```

FutureList because I want to state different queries in parallel. I need to access all books and all authors, thus I have to iterate through all books and all their authors:

```
for(Book b : books){
    List<Author> authors = b.authors;
    for (Author a : authors){
        ...
    }
}
```

It works but the iteration in the inner loop is very slow, much slower than querying the tables `book`, `book_author` and `author` seperately. I suppose that Ebean fetches the authors one at a time. 
Is there a faster way to do that?

Using `@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` doesn't change the retrieval speed.

**Update 05.02.2014**

I create the query this way:

```
Query<Book> queryBooks = Ebean.createQuery(Book.class);
FutureList<Book> fLBooks = queryBooks.fetch("authors", "*").where("...").findFutureList();
```

The resulting Ebean query is

```
select 
t0.book_id c0, 
t1.author_id c0
from book t0 
left outer join book_author t1z_ on t1z_.book_id = t0.book_id  
left outer join author t1 on t1.author_id = t1z_.author_id  
where MATCH (t0.text) AGAINST ('...' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by t0.book_id
```

**Good:** Ebean generates single query now. 
**Bad:** still 20 times slower than querying the tables `book`, `book_author` and `author` seperately. Maybe the mysql query optimizer does not its work?

Comment: And how do you get the list of books initially?

Comment: See my update (code to create the query and fetch its results).

Answer (score 1):

Hm, why don't use common Ebean's `Finder` and fighting with things like `@JoinColumn` yourself? Ebean's advantage is keeping things really simple, the same models written in right way are:

**Book**

```java
@Entity
public class Book extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;
    public static Finder<Integer, Book> find = new Finder<>(Integer.class, Book.class);

    public String title;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<Author> authors;

}
```

**Author**

```java
@Entity
public class Author extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;
    public static Finder<Integer, Author> find = new Finder<>(Integer.class, Author.class);

    public String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors") // take care about this mappedBy annotation, otherwise Ebean will want to use second JoinColumn
    public List<Book> books;

}
```

Next turn on SQL logging by adding this into your `application.conf`

```
db.default.logStatements = true
logger.com.jolbox = DEBUG
```

and compare execution of:

```java
String out = "";
List<Book> books = Book.find.findList();
for (Book book : books)
    for (Author author : book.authors)  
        out += "Book " + book.title + " by " + author.name + "\n";
```

versus:

```java
String out = "";
List<Book> books = Book.find.fetch("authors", "*").findList();
for (Book book : books)
    for (Author author : book.authors)  
        out += "Book " + book.title + " by " + author.name + "\n";
```

In general you're right, with first way it performs additional query for each book, in second just one query is executed.

And in opposite direction:

```java
String out = "";
List<Author> authors = Author.find.findList();
for (Author author : authors)
    for (Book book : author.books)
        out += author.name + " wrote this book: " + book.title + "\n";
```

versus:

```java
String out = "";
List<Author> authors = Author.find.fetch("books", "*").findList();
for (Author author : authors)
    for (Book book : author.books)
        out += author.name + " wrote this book: " + book.title + "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, but the single query doesn't bring the expected improvement of speed. it's still 20 times slower than than querying the tables book, book_author and author seperately (2secs to 100ms). See update. Btw I can't use the naming of Ebean, because the tables already exist and I am building a WebApp on top of it.